# Getting the first string after a symbol in a line of text python

Tags: python

I have a text line and i want to assign a variable to a certain string which appears directly after the symbol '@' in this line of text

```
09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician 0 013 @ 09623038 n 0000
```

The only thing is that this word may not appear in the same location so I can't just go like this

```
L = line.split()
K = L[-2]
```

It has to be searched as the first string after the '@' symbol. That is the only place it remains constant.

what i would like is for `K = 09623038`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split on `@` and then split whatever comes after it.

```
before_at, after_at = line.split('@')
K = int(after_at.split()[0])
```

For extra efficiency, if you only want the first thing after the `@`, do `after_at.split(None, 1)` -- that only splits once (on whitespace).

This will raise an exception when there's more than one `@`, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @kindall: except that `partition` returns the `@` as well, which is kind of useless here :)

Comment: Unfortunately i have found a line with two '@' symbols, which means there may be more, how do i get it so that it is just split at the first @ symbol? @kindall

Comment: @Johnnerz: `split('@', 1)` to split only once.

Answer (score 1):

[Partition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) is your friend:

```
>>> s='09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician 0 013 @ 09623038 n 0000'
>>> s.rpartition('@')
('09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician 0 013 ', '@', ' 09623038 n 0000')
>>> k=int(s.rpartition('@')[-1].split()[0])
>>> k
9623038
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = '09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician 0 013 @ 09623038 n 0000'
>>> re.search(r'@\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+)',strs).group(1)
'09623038'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer going a non-regex route, here's a function that'll solve your problem

```
def findVariable( s ):
    try:
        start = s.index( "@ " ) + 2
        end = s.index( " ", start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

print(findVariable("09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician 0 013 @ 09623038 n 0000"))
```

Returns: `09623038`